# TouchTouch gallery doesn't function when gallery is loaded with .click function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a gallery [here](https://bloogum.net/fanart.php) which has two states, sorting by artist or sorting by character. I have a simple .click function to make the appropriate gallery load, which works perfectly well (if slow-loading, plan on making a pre-loader or something later, maybe).

In addition to that, I'm using the [TouchTouch](https://tutorialzine.com/2012/04/mobile-touch-gallery) gallery for the mobile version. On its own, this also works perfectly well: [here](https://bloogum.net/fanart-b.php) it is in action without the .click function.

When the gallery loads on its own, TouchTouch works fine, but when I load it with the .click function, it doesn't.

I've tried moving the script that loads TouchTouch around, from the external main.js file, into the header of the main page and into the php file that loads the individual galleries, but nothing seems to work. I'm assuming it's something to do with the time at which it's loading but I don't know enough about jQuery/etc to know what else to do.

The .click function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#m-sortby-artist").click(function(){
        $("#mob-fanart").load("sort/byartist.php");
    });
});
```

The div in question:

```
<span id="m-sortby-artist">Sort by Artist</span> &middot; <span id="m-sortby-char">Sort by Character</span></p>
<div id="mob-fanart"></div>
```

The XML that creates the gallery, if that's useful, but I don't think it really comes into it:

```
<div class="mobile">
    <div class="gallery-mobile" data-gallery="one" id="m-sallie"></div>
    <script>
        var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "sort/byartist.xml", false);
        xmlhttp.send();
        xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("fanart");
        div="<h3>By Sallie<br><span class='artist-link'>@ <a href='https://rigaffe.co.uk'>Rigaffe</a></span></h3>";
        for (i = 0; i <82; i++) {
          div += "<a href='images/fanart/";
          div += x[i].getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          div += "/"
          div += x[i].getElementsByTagName("filename")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          div += "'><div class='";
          div += x[i].getElementsByTagName("class")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          div += "' style='background-image:url(images/fanart/";
          div += x[i].getElementsByTagName("artist")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          div += "/t/"
          div += x[i].getElementsByTagName("filename")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
          div += ");'></div><div class='thumb-box'></div></a>";
        }
        document.getElementById("m-sallie").innerHTML = div;
    </script>
</div>
```

Initialise TouchTouch:

```
$(function(){
    $('.gallery-mobile a').touchTouch();
});
```

The bulk of the TouchTouch code is unchanged from what comees out of the box, just some purely cosmetic styling.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it! Turns out there was one spot I hadn't tried putting the 'initiate TouchTouch' script: right at the end of the main gallery div. Success!